# Rearange json file contents by certain criteria

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have some data in a Google Spreadsheet. I used a php script to convert a .csv file into a .json file.

My results look like this:

```
    "Destination ": "Fuerteventura",
    "Hotel_name": "Aloe Club",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;Lejligheder op til 6 personer;;Tre dejlige poolområder ",
    "Fra-pris": "1234",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 0
},
{
    "Destination ": "Fuerteventura",
    "Hotel_name": "SunConnect Atlantis Fuerteventura Resort",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;All Inclusive indgår;;Mange aktiviteter for hele familien ",
    "Fra-pris": "123",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 1
},
```

I would like to know which would be the best way to rearange the contents in this way, so that all the hotels in Fuerteventura will be  a child of the fuertaventura destination. Something like this.

```
"Destination ": "Fuerteventura"{
    "Hotel_name": "Aloe Club",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;Lejligheder op til 6 personer;;Tre dejlige poolområder ",
    "Fra-pris": "1234",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 0,


    "Hotel_name": "SunConnect Atlantis Fuerteventura Resort",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;All Inclusive indgår;;Mange aktiviteter for hele familien ",
    "Fra-pris": "123",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 1
},
```

I am guessing that maybe some JavaScript code would do the trick but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: I don't see how JavaScript comes into play here. Do you want to restructure the data after it was sent to the client? If so, this has nothing to do with JSON or text files or PHP. You are merely asking how to iterate over an array and create an object with that structure. Or do you want to store the data like this in the file?

Comment: Yes, I want the data to be saved in this way to the file

Comment: Then update your PHP script to generate that structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want you json ordered in this way, because you can't have two attributes in an json object with the same name (example: your hotel id).

```
{
"Fuerteventura": [{
    "Hotel_name": "Aloe Club",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;Lejligheder op til 6 personer;;Tre dejlige poolområder ",
    "Fra-pris": "1234",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 0,
  },
  {
    "Hotel_name": "SunConnect Atlantis Fuerteventura Resort",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;All Inclusive indgår;;Mange aktiviteter for hele familien ",
    "Fra-pris": "123",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 1
  }]
}
```

and your readed in json should be in an array like that:

```
[{
    "Destination ": "Fuerteventura",
    "Hotel_name": "Aloe Club",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;Lejligheder op til 6 personer;;Tre dejlige poolområder ",
    "Fra-pris": "1234",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 0
},
{
    "Destination ": "Fuerteventura",
    "Hotel_name": "SunConnect Atlantis Fuerteventura Resort",
    "USP": "Børnevenligt;;All Inclusive indgår;;Mange aktiviteter for hele familien ",
    "Fra-pris": "123",
    "Se_flere_rejser_URL": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/vinterferie",
    "Læs_mere_her_URL ": "http:\/\/www.spies.dk\/de-kanariske-oer\/corralejo\/hoteller",
    "Image_url": "https:\/\/spies-isobar.s3.amazonaws.com\/1355_Spies_AVO\/cp\/destination\/a\/a\/image1.jpg",
    "id": 1
}]
```

The javascript to convert your json could look like this code:

```
var yourFirstJson; //contains your unordered json object
var yourSecondJson; //contains ordered json

//loop through all destination of your input json
for(var destination in yourFirstJson) {

    //Name of your destination, will be the new json attribute
    var destinationName = destination.Destination;

    //delete the "Destination" name attribute what is still in your added object (i think you don't want it in your new json)
    delete destination.Destination;

    //add the destination as attribute of your second object or add an hotel to the array in this attribute
    yourSecondJson[destinationName].push(destination);

}
```

I hope that helps you...